# creating assembly files for third party libraries

Tags: unity, assembly

I basically have a huge project and we just came to know about assembly definitions could speed up our compile time. I've got a lot of libraries hooked in, and when I tried to simply add an `assembly definition` file to my project directory for the plugins all sorts of error started to popup.

One of the error was this which was from the megafiers asset: [from the asset store](https://assetstore.unity.com/publishers/382)
`Assets/MegaFiers/Scripts/MegaFiers/Modifiers/MegaDisplace.cs(60,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BurstCompileAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

The place I put the assembly definition was like this:

```
---Assets
  |-plugin 1
  |-plugin 2
  |-Megafiers
  |  \-Burst 
  |  \-Editor
  |  \-MegaControllers
  |  \-Utils
  |-AssemblyDefinition
```

So, I'm kind of just suspecting that since all the assets are jabbed into AssemblyDefinition maybe the assembly definition didn't contain non-code files such as materials, prefabs etc? I'm just guessing though, I have minimal knowledge on the subject. Please give me some insight on solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Also, some of these libraries seem to have code in the `Editor` folder. From the docs, these code get compiled into the default assembly file(assembly-csharp). But, doesn't that file change each time we make code changes? So, what's the point of a library creating `asmdef`s to a place that always changes?

EDIT2: For the clarification on my question edit. And, taking instance of the Megafiers library above, The editor folder seems to get compiled into the `assembly-csharp-editor` dll and other files, inside this library, don't seem to be associated with a dll file other than `assembly-csharp` which happens to get recompiled when we make a change. Since these code also don't change at all, it would make sense to build a dll for them as well(?). But, when I add an assembly definition to the `Megafiers` folder, it gives errors like mentioned above in the question. And the reason was that code in the library was being referenced(e.g. class was being used) in some part of the project. In this case, how do we create a dll for the `Megafiers` library?

Comment: 1) It looks to me like you already figured out the answer by experiment. 2) Editor code does not get compiled into the default assembly, but into an editor-only assembly. I'd be interested in what passage from the docs would lead you to believe otherwise. 3) Editor code generally is *not* always changing. In fact, it changes fairly rarely unless you're actively developing a new editor tool. Can you edit your question to clarify what it is you need outside help with?

Comment: @DMGregory , but I can't find the place in the doc that says assembly-csharp-editor.dll doesn't change when source code changes, but assembly-chasharp.dll does change?

Comment: I can only find stuffs that say everything goes into the assembly-csharp.dll by default and when some code changes everything gets recompiled, but nothing about the editor dll.

Comment: "by default" is the clue. If the folder is not called editor and there's not another assembly definition, then the base game assembly is chosen by default. Editor folders have their own assembly that is not the default.

Comment: I see. But, what's the difference between these besides the order they get compiled as stated here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html . Also , if the library has bunch of code that's not in the editor folder as seen in the Megafiers above, would putting them into a separate Assembly def file increase compilation time?

Comment: Editor code is available in the editor, and does not get included in the built game. As for whether a potential optimization would improve compilation speed, that sounds like a question you can answer experimentally.

Comment: That's true as well. However when I try to do that, numerous errors popup like above. I was just wondering whether generating assemblies like that is recommended. Because, if it were good the author would have possibly precompiled the code into dlls, right? Should it be done or not?

Comment: @DMGregory , is it possible to create assembly files for files that are being referenced from the outside? Or should the files be a black box-able isolated peice of code. In the former case, how would we approach it, because, it seems errors popup otherwise.

Comment: Sounds like you should **edit your question** to clarify what you're asking. You've already determined that non-code files don't go in assemblies (code is the only thing that gets compiled into an assembly, by definition), so what is the problem you need help solving?

Answer (score 1):

just found your question while checking if someone had built asmdefs for Megafiers.  Since it was the top hit, I'll put mine here and have a stab at answering your question (although you've probably moved on give its age)!

## General asmdefs background = The goal

We want code that doesn't change often not to be compiled every time we change our code.

### Asmdefs

All code in the same or sub-directories as an asmdef gets included in that asmdef's DLL.

So, easy, we put all asssets (which don't change often) in their own asmdef(s) and *our code* (that does change often) in its own asmdef(s).

#### Hitch 1

asmdefs separate code so you can't access the asset's methods!
Well, in come references.  When our code wishes to reference things in those other asmdefs, we edit our asmdef to add references to the assets'.

### Editor code

Without asmdefs, any code under a directory named "Editor" gets added to the "`Assembly-CSharp-Editor`" assembly and anything outside it goes in "`Assembly-CSharp`" (caveat see Plugins below).

### Plugins

Anything under an "`Editor`" directory under "`Plugins`" goes in "`Assembly-CSharp-Editor-firstpass`" and under "`Plugins`" but not "`Editor`" is "`Assembly-CSharp-firstpass`".  Before asmdefs, this was how we achieved compilation time speedups -- move everything under here!

#### Hitch 2

When we add an asmdef, *all* code under it goes in the asmdef's DLL.  That includes all the "Editor" code which won't have reference to Editor methods and will then get included in the build which won't work and cause everything to fail!  nooo.

So, every "`Editor`" directory needs its own asmdef.  This says the code next-to-and-under is Editor-only.  Obviously that Editor code will need to reference the top-level asset asmdef!  For some assets, there's a single "`Editor`" directory so it's 1 extra asmdef.  For some, it's ... well, let's say quite a few.  I've ended up moving things around to reduce numbers since, while compile time is large when lots of source files are compiled in one go, if you get lots of DLLs needing linking, that can cause time to shoot up too!

## Megafiers!  (finally)

Megafiers 2 (which I'm using) uses Burst.  I've included all the files needed below.
(I don't have Megafierrs 1 (pre-Burst) but I'd hazard you just omit "`Unity.Burst`", "`Unity.Collections`", "`Unity.Jobs`" and "`Unity.Mathematics`".)

One non-Editor asmdef at top level `Assets/MegaFiers/Scripts/Megafiers.asmdef`:

```
{
  "name": "Megafiers",
  "references": [
    "Unity.Burst",
    "Unity.Collections",
    "Unity.Jobs",
    "Unity.Mathematics",
    "Unity.ProBuilder",
    "Unity.TextMeshPro"
  ]
}
```

One in the first "`Editor`" directory `Assets/MegaFiers/Scripts/MegaFiers/Editor/Megafiers.Editor.asmdef`:

```
{
  "name": "Megafiers.Editor",
  "references": [
    "Megafiers",
    "Unity.ProBuilder",
    "Unity.TextMeshPro"
  ],
  "includePlatforms": ["Editor"]
}
```

And lastly another in the "`MegaShapes`" sub-directory `Assets/MegaFiers/Scripts/MegaShape/Editor/Megafiers.MegaShapes.Editor.asmdef`:

```
{
  "name": "Megafiers.MegaShapes.Editor",
  "references": [
    "Megafiers",
    "Megafiers.Editor",
    "Unity.ProBuilder",
    "Unity.TextMeshPro"
  ],
  "includePlatforms": ["Editor"]
}
```

Lastly, in your main project's asmdef, you'll need to reference "`Megafiers`" and now you should be set to go!  (at least for Megafiers ;) ).
HTH & GL